# `ctx.cookies` is always undefined in apollo-server-koa

Tags: cookies, graphql, apollo, koa, apollo-server-koa

I'm using `apollo-server-koa` and created a simple Koa app + ApolloServer but when I want to access `ctx.cookies` in the GraphQL resolvers, it's always `undefined`. Only `request` and `response` are there.

```js
const app = new Koa()
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: ({ ctx }) => ctx
})

server.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
  }
})
```

It confuses me because when I do `app.use((ctx) => ...)`, `cookies` is available.
Is this correct and do I need a separate cookie middleware like `cookie-parser` in express?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike express, the cookie functionality for koa is in a separate package 'koa-cookie'.

If you do:

```js
import cookie from 'koa-cookie';
const app = new Koa();
app.use(cookie());
```

You should be able to set and get cookies through ctx.cookies.set and ctx.cookies.get.

Comment: This package seems greatly out of date and unmaintained. Is there any alternative? Seems like https://github.com/pillarjs/cookies would be a better alternative, while not so intuitive?